# How to control the source of AWS network load balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

2 questions on NLB in AWS

1. I have a requirement to use NLB in front of the EC2 which runs MYSQL. This EC2 is in private network. I just want to allow NLB to be accessed by some particular internet IP. If it's ALB, I can use security group to do this. However, without security group in NLB, how can I achieve this?
2. In this setup, I connect to NLB from my PC and reach to that MYSQL EC2. To make it success, I find that I have to allow 0.0.0.0/0 in the incoming rule of the EC2 security group instead of just putting my PC IP. I thought my PC IP should be brought to EC2 directly through NLB. Is it not true? I dont want to allow 0.0.0.0/0 in EC2 security group. Is there any better way?

Thanks!

Comment: thanks all. I finally need to whitelist both the NLB internal IP and the PC public IP to make the whitelisting work. The target type is set to instance in NLB

Answer (score 3):

The security group evaluations are performed by the instances security groups for the Network Load Balancer. You would need to add the IP addresses you would like to communicate with the NLB to your instances, as long as your instance is in a private subnet this will prevent any client directly interacting with the host.

> Network Load Balancers do not have associated security groups. Therefore, the security groups for your targets must use IP addresses to allow traffic from the load balancer.

More information is available in the [Register targets with your target group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/target-group-register-targets.html) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to block the traffic in your case is to have the IPs to which you want to allow access in the EC2 SG.

However you need to account for the fact that there is a difference on the IP address from which the request will come from and thus will be evaluated from the EC2 SG based on how you have configured the target group of the NLB and more specifically on whether you have set up the target type to be **instance** or **ip**, as there is a difference in the NLB behaviour.

- If the target type is set to **instance**, the NLB will pass the traffic to your instance as is, and the EC2 SG will see your locap PC public IP address, and if there is a rule to allow it you will be able to connect
- If the target type is set to **ip**, the NLB is doing an NAT, and the EC2 SG will actually see the private IP of the NLB as a source IP for the incoming traffic.

Take a look at the Source IP Preservation in the [NLB Target Group documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/load-balancer-target-groups.html#target-type).

There is a [similar discussion in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60431236/how-to-limit-the-access-to-ec2-from-nlb-only).